# Javascript clearTimeout not working even with timer Variable Available To All Functions

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have read almost every thread on here about clearing a JS timer and nothing seems to be working. Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var timeout;

  $('#chat_link').click(function() {

    var id = str_replace('chat_', '', $(this).attr('alt'));

    $.ajax({
      async: false,
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/members/functions/private_message_handler.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: 'member=' + id + '&action=get_old_messages',
      success: function(data, textStatus) {
        $('#chat_name').html(data.name);
        $('#message_area').html(data.messages);
        $('#chat_window').show();
        $('#message_area').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#message_area').get(0).scrollHeight
        }, 100);
        $('#message_member_id').val(id);
      }

    });

    get_messages(id, timeout);

  });

  $('#close_chat').click(function() {
    $('#chat_window').hide();
    $('#chat_name').html('');
    $('#message_area').html('');
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  });


  (function($) {

    get_messages = function(member_id, timeout) {

      var time = 3000;

      timeout = setTimeout(

        function() {

          $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/members/functions/private_message_handler.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'member=' + member_id + '&action=get_old_messages',
            success: function(data, textStatus) {
              $('#message_area').html(data.messages);
              $('#message_area').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#message_area').get(0).scrollHeight
              }, 100);
              get_messages(member_id);
            }

          });

        },
        time
      );

    };

  })(jQuery);

});
```

As you can see I made the timeout variable outside of all the functions so everything could 'see' it and I even tried passing it to the get_messages function. No matter what I do when the chat box is closed ($('#close_chat').click(function()) the script keeps running. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but obviously something isn't right

Comment: Because you hit the state when the timeout already ran and the Ajax call is already running. Cancelling the timeout will do nothing. you would need to abort the active Ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timeout = setTimeout(...)` in your `get_messages` function changes the value of your local variable `timeout`, and not the one defined at the very beginning of your script. Primitive types are passed by value in javascript, you can't pass them by reference.

You can store your `timeout` id inside an object and pass this object instead of the primitive value. Also you need to cancel the next request when you close your chat.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        timeout: null,
        isChatVisible: false
    };

    $('#chat_link').click(function() {
        options.isChatVisible = true;

        var id = str_replace('chat_', '', $(this).attr('alt'));

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/members/functions/private_message_handler.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'member=' + id + '&action=get_old_messages',
            success: function(data, textStatus) {
                $('#chat_name').html(data.name);
                $('#message_area').html(data.messages);
                $('#chat_window').show();
                $('#message_area').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#message_area').get(0).scrollHeight
                }, 100);
                $('#message_member_id').val(id);
            }

        });

        get_messages(id, options);

    });

    $('#close_chat').click(function() {
        $('#chat_window').hide();
        $('#chat_name').html('');
        $('#message_area').html('');
        clearTimeout(options.timeout);
        options.isChatVisible = false;
    });


    (function($) {

        get_messages = function(member_id, options) {

            var time = 3000;

            options.timeout = setTimeout(

                function() {

                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/members/functions/private_message_handler.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: 'member=' + member_id + '&action=get_old_messages',
                        success: function(data, textStatus) {
                            // stop polling the server if chat is closed
                            if (!options.isChatVisible) {
                                return;
                            }

                            $('#message_area').html(data.messages);
                            $('#message_area').animate({
                                scrollTop: $('#message_area').get(0).scrollHeight
                            }, 100);
                            get_messages(member_id, options);
                        }

                    });

                },
                time
            );

        };

    })(jQuery);

});
```

Comment: Man, horrible formatted code strikes again.... I thought you were insane, more like removing the freaking `timeout` would fix it. Still has the issue with my comment where the Ajax call can still be active which means calls would still keep running. Ajax call needs to be aborted or needs some flag to not create the next call when it is done.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, OP definitely needs a better mechanism to manage the requests, but that's a different issue I guess.

Comment: @epascarello Actually it'd be better to use setInterval/clearInterval here instead of setTimeout/clearTimeout.

Comment: Intervals are a bad idea with synchronous requests unless you want to also kill off any request that may have not retuned. Your server could be lagging big time and a short enough request could have a queue of Ajax calls waiting to go out.  setTimeout way ensures that the call is done before sending out the next. Either way, the Ajax call needs to be aborted.

Comment: @epascarello Good point about the server lag, haven't thought of that.